# Django: Module not found error , on importing a model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I am fairly new to Django, in my project I have created 2 apps, web, and dashboard while trying to import my model from the web to model in the app dashboard using '''from myproject.web import models'''   I am getting the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject.web'.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from web.models import *
```

this will work